# jwt token multi tenancy

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I implemented in my ASP.NET Core project Web API user authorization via token. I create a token at each login and everything seems to work.

My problem is that the app will be multi-tenancy, so I will have many subdomains client-side, e.g.
(Client1.myapp.com, client2.myapp.com, client3.myapp.com)

Server-side my app that manages the bees will accept a parameter that will be the name of the tenant.

Some examples:

> apimyapp.com/client1/api/generateToken
>
> apimyapp.com/client2/api/generateToken
>
> apimyapp.com/client3/api/generateToken

Now if I create the token from client1 and I put in a call apimyapp.com/client2/api/users (insert token generated by the client1 in the header, but the call is made for the client2), the token will be validated and the call gets authorized.

Instead, I wish that the token was valid only for the tenant from which it was generated.

In my startup.cs:

```
 app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = _config["Tokens:Audience"],
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"])),
                ValidateLifetime = true
            }
        });
```

and in my controller for generation token:

```
    var userClaims =  _userManagerRepository.GetClaims(user);

    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, user.UserName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName, user.UserName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email)
    }.Union(userClaims);

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
        audience: _config["Tokens:Audience"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(90),
        signingCredentials: creds
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a list on keys, Audiences etc like this to the TokenValidationParameters

```
  ValidAudiences = new List<string> 
        {
            "AUDIENCE1",
            "AUDIENCE2" 
        }
```

Comment: What if I have requests coming from multiple domains and they have their own JWT issuer and audience address, how can this be configured?